# BroadcastReceiver makes app crash when app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When app is running no problem occurs but if I close my app and change the date to the date I specified to be reminded at the app crashes 
Permissions:

```
  <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
String name = "";
int id = 0;
String releaseDate = "";
// Called when a broadcast is made targeting this class
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Set the alarm here.
        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        for (Alarm alarm: MyApp.myAlarmsDB.getAllData()){
            alertIntent.putExtra("id", Integer.parseInt(alarm.get_id()));
            alertIntent.putExtra("name", alarm.get_name());
            alertIntent.putExtra("releaseDate", alarm.get_releaseDate());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarm.get_id()), alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Long.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(alarm.get_alertTime())), pendingIntent);
        }

    } else {
        Intent intActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intActivity);

        id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra("releaseDate");

        //delete from database
        MyApp.myAlarmsDB.deleteFromId(String.valueOf(id));
    }

    createNotification(context, "Gaming Reminder", name + ": " + releaseDate, "Gaming Reminder", id);
}
```

}

Unfortunately no stack-trace gets printed

Comment: "Unfortunately no stack-trace gets printed " -- then how do you know that your app crashes?

Comment: Message in the emulator, but seriously do you have any idea why no stack-trace gets printed?

Comment: I suspect strongly that a stack trace *is* being sent to LogCat. Note that it may show up with warning severity, instead of the normal error severity.

Comment: Not even a line gets printed in logcat

Comment: No one can help me :(